# Xpath gets the expected value but in the root tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to take the xpath on an XML document.

Problem:
the xpath gets me the expected value (within the root tags of the XML document

I want only the value in the position of the xpath without the root
tag.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide the example you are running on Xpath?

Comment: We can't tell what you did wrong unless you tell us what you did. Please be as precise as possible: tell us what's in the source document, what XPath expression you executed, and how you processed the result.